# Haskell: associating a polymorphic function for each level in a tree

Tags: haskell, tree, polymorphism

Good day!

I have a tree of elements:

```
data Tree a = Node [Tree a]
            | Leaf a
```

I need to get to the leaf of that tree. The path from the root to the leaf is determined by a sequence of `switch` functions. Each layer in that tree corresponds to a specific `switch` function that takes something as a parameter and returns an index to the subtree.

```
class Switchable a where
    getIndex :: a -> Int

data SwitchData = forall c. Switchable c => SwitchData c
```

The final goal is to provide a function that expects all necessary `SwitchData` and returns
the leaf in a tree.

But I see no way
to enforce the one-to-one mapping at type-level. My current implementation of `switch`
functions accepts a list of `SwitchData` instances:

```
switch :: SwitchData -> Tree a -> Tree a
switch (SwitchData c) (Node vec) = vec `V.unsafeIndex` getIndex c
switch _ _ = error "switch: performing switch on a Leaf of context tree"

switchOnData :: [SwitchData] -> Tree a -> a
switchOnData (x:xs) tree = switchOnData xs $ switch x tree
switchOnData [] (Leaf c) = c
switchOnData [] (Node _) = error "switchOnData: partial data"
```

The order and the exact types of `Switchable` instances
are not considered neither at compile time nor at runtime, the correctness is left for a programmer, which bothers me a lot. That [gist](https://gist.github.com/ownclo/8308388) reflects the current state of affair.

Could you suggest some ways of establishing that one-to-one mapping between layers in a context tree and particular instances of `Switchable`?

Comment: I don't understand at all what you are trying to do, but it seems highly unlikely you need a typeclass for this.

Comment: @TomEllis, I've probably started to explain the wrong thing. I need to get a leaf from a tree. Each level has a corresponding switcher which allows me to dig one step deeper. Can I implement a function that takes the data for switchers at all levels and gives me a leaf?

Comment: Is the idea that you follow a route to the leaf determined by the switchers you encounter?

Comment: Almost so. I follow a route to the leaf which is determined by data that I provide. But each switcher define the _type_ of data that it needs to make a decision. So a route to the leaf is determined by both switchers and data provided for them.

Comment: Your current implementation accepts "a _list of `Switchable` instances_"?? There is no such thing in Haskell. What do you mean, a list of some existential data type? — Perhaps you should present / link the entire code so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: Well, there's both `Switchable a => [a]` which is a list of things of a type that instantiates `Switchable` and there's also `data Switch a = forall a . Switchable a => Switch a` letting us write `[Switch]`. Both are pretty strange things to ask for in this circumstance, though.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, that's true, I've wrapped that `Switchable` into an existential data type, sorry if that caused confusion, I'll edit the question. Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/ownclo/8308388) of the code.

Comment: What is wrong with `data SwitchFunc a = SF (Tree a -> Int)` and `switch :: SwitchFunc a -> Tree a -> Tree a; switch _ (Leaf x) = = Leaf x; switch (SF f) (Tree xs) = xs !! (f xs)`. Your `Switchable` class is literally just `Enum` in your example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Your current solution](https://gist.github.com/ownclo/8308388) is equivalent to simply `switchOnIndices :: [Int] -> Tree a -> a` (simply apply `getIndex` *before* storing in list!). Make this explicitly "partial" by wrapping the return in `Maybe` and this may actually be the ideal signature, simple and fine.

But apparently, your real use case is more complex; you want to have basically different *dictionaries* at each level. Then you actually need to link the multiple levels of types to those of tree depths. You're in for some crazy almost-dependent-typed hackery!

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeOperators, LambdaCase #-}

infixr 5 :&

data Nil = Nil
data s :& ss where
  (:&) :: s -> ss -> s :& ss

data Tree switch a where
  Node ::
     (s -> Tree ss a)  -- Such a function is equiv. to `Switchable c => (c, [Tree a])`.
     -> Tree (s :& ss) a
  Leaf :: a -> Tree Nil a

switch :: s -> Tree (s :& ss) a -> Tree ss a
switch s (Node f) = f s

switchOnData :: s -> Tree s a -> a
switchOnData sw (Node f) = switchOnData ss $ f s
 where (s :& ss) = sw
switchOnData _ (Leaf a) = a

data Sign = P | M

signTree :: Tree (Sign :& Sign :& Nil) Char
signTree = Node $ \case P -> Node $ \case P -> Leaf 'a'
                                          M -> Leaf 'b'
                        M -> Node $ \case P -> Leaf 'c'
                                          M -> Leaf 'd'

testSwitch :: IO()
testSwitch = print $ switchOnData (P :& M :& Nil) signTree

main = testSwitch
```

Of course, this greatly limits the flexibility of the tree structure: each level has a fixed predetermined number of nodes. In fact, that makes the entire structure of e.g. `signTree` equivalent to simply `(Sign, Sign) -> Char`, so unless you really need a tree for some specific reason (e.g. extra information attached to the nodes), why not just use that!

Or, again, the way simpler `[Int] -> Tree a -> a` signature. But using *existentials* makes no sense to me at all here.

Comment: I do need different dictionaries for each level indeed. You're right about `switchOnIndices` as well and you've got the question right. Your answer works well and seems to do the right thing, but I will surely have a funny time understanding it.

Comment: Each level _need to have_ the fixed number of nodes that will never change at runtime. The need for a tree arises for a reason: I want to have a convenient way to _construct_ such `(Sign, Sign) -> Char` from two different functions `Sign -> Int` and `Sign -> Int`, one per tree level. Will I be able to get rid of your lambda cases and replace them with index-based functions?

Comment: The lambda-cases are just syntactic sugar anyway. — I still doubt that you really need any explicit tree structure. In procedural languages, sure... but this is Haskell after all, and you can replace an awful lot of explicit data with its lambda-calculus equivalents pretty nicely. Functions' domain is basically _codata_, look it up in blog posts.

Comment: I'll try to avoid explicit tree. My goal was to minimise the effort in swapping types on which the decision is made. Imagine the amount of work required to place yet another sign on top of that type stack. Or to swap from `Sign` to some `Bar` somewhere in the middle. Anyway, your solution addresses exactly the question in the OP. Thank you a lot, your answer is a great foundation for further investigations!

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. As you suggested, moving away from actual tree data structure was a good idea. I've ended up with a very simple type with `switch` function in it. [Here](https://gist.github.com/ownclo/8359144#file-switcher-hs) is the gist for it.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that we're traversing a `Tree` at a particular `Node` and have our particular kind of desired polymorphic `Switchable` value available as well. In other words, we want to take a `step`

```
step :: Switchable -> Tree a -> Maybe (Tree a)
```

Here the output `Tree` is one of the children of the input `Tree` and we wrap it in a `Maybe` just in case something goes wrong. So let's try to write `step`

```
step s Leaf{} = Nothing
step s (Node children) = switch s (?extract children)
```

Here, the challenge arises out of defining `?extract` as we need it to polymorphically produce the right kind of value for `switch s` to operate on. We can't meaningfully use polymorphism to get this to work:

```
-- won't work!
class Extractable b where
  extract :: [Tree a] -> b
```

since now `switch . extract` is ambiguous. In fact, if `Switchable` operates by existentially quantifying a value that it needs passed in then there is *no way* (outside of `Typeable`) to build an `extract` that works properly. Instead, we need each `Switchable` to have its own individual `extract` with the proper type, a type that only exists inside of the context of the data type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Switchable = forall pass . Switchable 
  { extract :: [Tree a] -> pass
  , switch  :: pass     -> Int
  }

step s (Node children) = children `safeLookup` switch s (extract s children)
```

But due to the containment of this existential type, we know that there's absolutely no way to use a `Switchable` except to immediately compute the existentially hidden `pass` value and then consume it with `switch`. There's not even any reason to store `pass` since the only way we can get any information out of it is to use `switch`.

Altogether this leads to the intuition that `Switchable` ought to be this instead.

```
data Switchable = Switchable { switch :: [Tree a] -> Int }

step s (Node children) = children `safeLookup` switch s children
```

Or even

```
data Switchable = Switchable { switch :: [Tree a] -> Tree a }

step s (Node children) = Just (switch s children)
```

Comment: I doubt if this really answers the OP's question, but you're making some good points. It appears the OP's definitions are even simpler; their `SwitchData` is in fact equivalent to just `Int`.

Comment: You assume that the type of the `Switchable` determines the step. That's not true. The type _and_ the value are both needed for that.In other words, your function `switch` should be of type `value -> [Tree a] -> Tree a`

Comment: Ah! This is written before the op posted code so I may have misunderstood the question

Comment: @J.Abrahamson I am really sorry for that. That question is just not so easy to explain.

Comment: @ownclo I don't see why `switch :: value -> [Tree a] -> Tree a` is any more powerful than `Switchable` with `extract` and `switch`. Since `extract` already builds a `value` by using a list of children and we only have one set of children during the traversal, I can't see how letting `switch` consume that list *again* adds any more information.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson That's because that `value` cannot be built from a list of children. We do not `extract` anything from it. That is not our source of information. The information on the exact steps is provided from _outside_.